# How to import a custom node.js addon module using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, node-modules

I have a custom Node.js addon that I've written, but I'd like to use typescript.  I can use bindings to import the module in JavaScript

```
const addon = require('bindings')('addon');
```

which will import addon.node from build/release/

How can I do this using TypeScript?  Does it allow addon import?

Comment: Actually this is all you need. This will work. But, if you want code completion, you should create tsd scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [create a declaration file](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files) that adds type information for your addon module, and then [import it using a relative path](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) in TypeScript.

For good examples of declaration files for external modules, see the [DefinitelyTyped GitHub repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). A succinct good example from that directory is the [declaration for the `camelcase` NPM nodule](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/camelcase/index.d.ts):

```
declare module "camelcase" {
    function camelcase(...args: string[]): string;
    namespace camelcase {}
    export = camelcase;
}
```

Comment: the link to camelcase npm module is broken

Comment: What I find difficult to figure out is how to package the declaration module and some typescript wrapper objects all into the addon module project folder and then install it in the consumer app via 'npm i -s ...'.