# ESM import a .node addon

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to import a .node binary addon in an ESM & Node Typescript based context. However, when I try to do this I get the following error "error TS2307: Cannot find module './addon.node' or its corresponding type declarations."

I've looked online for several solutions, these are my versions:
NodeJS: v16.14.1
ts-node: v10.7.0
Typescript: 4.6.3

This is my current approach for importing:

```js
import addon from "./addon.node";
```

Just to note, because of my configuration I am limited to only using import.
Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a custom node.js addon module using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876974/how-to-import-a-custom-node-js-addon-module-using-typescript)

Comment: The answer is not really direct in that post.

Comment: It should be a step in the right direction, because the error you are getting is not related to not being able to import the file, it's due to the fact that there's no types in the node add-on. Follow the instructions and if that fails, update your question and report back.

Comment: This Q & A is not limited to Typescript, which I am _not_ using.

Answer (score 4):

Node.js `import` doesn’t support `.node` files. To import such files in an ESM context, you need to use `createRequire`:

```js
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const addon = require('./addon.node');
```

You could also import the `.node` file in a CommonJS file that an ESM file then imports.

```js
// addon.cjs
module.exports = require('./addon.node');

// main.js
import addon from './addon.cjs';
```

Finally, you could create an [ESM loader](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#loaders) that adds support for `.node` files to `import`, by wrapping the `createRequire` method into a loader (untested):

```js
import { cwd } from 'node:process';
import { pathToFileURL } from 'node:url';

const baseURL = pathToFileURL(`${cwd()}/`).href;

export async function resolve(specifier, context, nextResolve) {
  if (specifier.endsWith('.node')) {
    const { parentURL = baseURL } = context;

    // Node.js normally errors on unknown file extensions, so return a URL for
    // specifiers ending in `.node`.
    return {
      shortCircuit: true,
      url: new URL(specifier, parentURL).href,
    };
  }

  // Let Node.js handle all other specifiers.
  return nextResolve(specifier);
}

export async function load(url, context, nextLoad) {
  if (url.endsWith('.node')) {
    const source = `
      import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
      import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
      const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
      const path = fileURLToPath(${url});
      export default require(path);`;

    return {
      format: 'module',
      shortCircuit: true,
      source,
    };
  }

  // Let Node.js handle all other URLs.
  return nextLoad(url);
}
```